# Is it possible to embed in an iFrame a video chat page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to embed a page that does video chats. It shows the chat with no issues, but I can't participate as the page doesn't get my permissions to use the camera and the mic.

Is that something that could be be done with correct implementation? Or it just won't ever work?

I am currently using it with this library like this:

```
 <Iframe
    url="theconferenceusrl.com"
    width="100%"
    height="450px"
    id="myId"
    className="myClassname"
    display="initial"
    position="relative"
  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u try. for Iframe u can use allow attribute
[Check more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

```
 <Iframe
    url="theconferenceusrl.com"
    width="100%"
    height="450px"
    id="myId"
    className="myClassname"
    display="initial"
    position="relative"
    allow="camera; microphone"
  />
```